# Representation of spin group carrying a symplectic form

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, general-relativity, spin-geometry

I am currently studying the paper

*Parker, Thomas; Taubes, Clifford Henry*, [**On Witten’s proof of the positive energy theorem**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01208569), Commun. Math. Phys. 84, 223-238 (1982). [ZBL0528.58040](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0528.58040).  and have a question concerning the beginning of section 2:

Denote by $Cl_{3,1}$ the CLifford algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ with respect to a metric of signature (3,1).
We consider the spinor group Spin$_{3,1}$, which is isomorphic to the special linear group SL$(2,\mathbb{C})$. The (non-conjugate) spinor representation is then given by an irreducible representation of the even subalgebra $Cl^0_{3,1}$ over $\mathbb{C}$
$$ Cl^0_{3,1} \cong End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$$
such that the volume element $\omega = e_0...e_3$ acts as $i$ on $V$ ($e_0,...,e_3$ denoting the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$).

Now, it is claimed that the representation $V$ carries an invariant symplectic form $\sigma$. This is equivalent to the existence of an inner product $$(-,-): V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C},$$
expressed in matrix form by an invertible skew-hermitian matrix.

I am very puzzled by this as I am failing to see how this is induced by the described representation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.